# Tensorflow Label_Image for PNG, GIF etc

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, jpeg, classification

I was playing around with Tensorflow for image classification. I used the image_retraining/retrain.py to retrain the inception library with new categories and used it to classify images using label_image.py from https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_image_classifier/blob/master/src/label_image.py as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
    in tf.gfile.GFile("/root/tf_files/output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/root/tf_files/output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    #predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodePng/contents:0': image_data})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

I noticed two issues. When I retrain  with new categories, it only trains JPG images. I am a noob in machine learning so not sure whether this is a limitation or is it possible to train other extension images like PNG, GIF?

Another one is when classifying the images the input is again only for JPG. I tried to change DecodeJpeg to DecodePng in label_image.py above but couldn't work. Another way I tried was to convert other formats into JPG before passing them in for classification like:

```
im = Image.open('/root/Desktop/200_s.gif').convert('RGB')
im.save('/root/Desktop/test.jpg', "JPEG")
image_path1 = '/root/Desktop/test.jpg'
```

Is there any other way to do this? Does Tensorflow have functions to handle other image formats other than JPG?

I tried the following by feeding in parsed image as compared to JPEG as suggested by @mrry

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

image = Image.open(image_path)
image_array = np.array(image)[:,:,0:3]  # Select RGB channels only.

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
    in tf.gfile.GFile("/root/tf_files/output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/root/tf_files/output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

It works for JPEG images but when I use PNG or GIF it throws

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "label_image.py", line 17, in <module>
        image_array = np.array(image)[:,:,0:3]  # Select RGB channels only. 
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: About the `IndexError`, the error message suggest that `image` doesn't have three dimensions. What do you get if you do `print(np.array(image).shape)`? Can you try `np.asarray(image)` instead?

Comment: @mrry Able to make it work now. Did a image.convert('RGB') and feed in the array subsequently. Able to use JPG,PNG and GIF now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model can only train on (and evaluate) JPEG images, because the `GraphDef` that you've saved in `/root/tf_files/output_graph.pb` only contains a [`tf.image.decode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image/encoding_and_decoding#decode_jpeg) op, and uses the output of that op for making predictions. There are at least a couple of options for using other image formats:

1. **Feed in parsed images rather than JPEG data.** In the current program, you feed in a JPEG-encoded image as a string value for the tensor `"DecodeJpeg/contents:0"`. Instead, you can feed in a 3-D array of decoded image data for the tensor `"DecodeJpeg:0"` (which represents the *output* of the `tf.image.decode_jpeg()` op), and you can use NumPy, PIL, or some other Python library to create this array.
2. **Remap the image input in [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#import_graph_def).** The `tf.import_graph_def()` function enables you to connect two different graphs together by remapping individual tensor values. For example, you could do something like the following to add a new image-processing op to the existing graph:

   ```
   image_string_input = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
   image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string_input)

   # Unpersists graph from file
   with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/root/tf_files/output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
       graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
       softmax_tensor, = tf.import_graph_def(
           graph_def,
           input_map={"DecodeJpeg:0": image_decoded},
           return_operations=["final_result:0"])

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
       predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {image_string_input: image_data})
       # ...
   ```

Comment: I tried the first method as you suggested by feeding in parsed image (quote updated in my question). It works for JPEG but when I use PNG or GIF it throws "IndexError: too many indices for array" error. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you include the whole stack trace from the `IndexError` in the question?

Comment: Yup, have included the whole stack trace in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [`tf.image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image/) package. It's got good functions to decode / encode JPEGs, GIFs and PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

Following @mrry's suggestion to feed in parsed image, converted the image data into array and convert into RGB as stated below in the code. Now I am able to feed in JPG,PNG and GIF.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

image = Image.open(image_path)
image_array = image.convert('RGB')

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
    in tf.gfile.GFile("/root/tf_files/output_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/root/tf_files/output_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Comment: I have a question: related to `top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]`. How do I get the highest predicted value?

Comment: the short answer was, `label_lines[top_k[0]]` . Thanks!